# Send a message from a file every hour

Tags: javascript, discord

I would like to send a message from a text file every 24 hours to a channel in my server (discord.js).

I think it would be like "appendFile" or something like that. If you know how to do this I would appreciate it!

The way I am looking to use this is every morning with a random good morning message.

Comment: can u edit you question adding what u have tried?

Comment: what is your os?

Comment: I use repl.it  ''

Comment: Why don't you use a third party (free) service?

Comment: You can use a "serverless" service like [Amazon Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) which has a scheduling feature and can run JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` , here is what you can do -

```js
var fs = require("fs"); // require fs
var file = fs.readFileSync("./path/to/file"); // read file 
setInterval(()=>{
MessageChannel.send(file); // the `TextChannel` class
},86400000) // setting the time to 24 hours in ms
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a cron job.

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) is the one i use.

Install

```
npm install cron


var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
    console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
job.start();
```

You can read about cron patterns [here](http://crontab.org/)